# Cloning a task ("Create copy of work item...") doesn't copy its parent

Tags: azure-devops

When I'm cloning a task in certain story (clicking on the "Create copy of work item..." option from within the task), it creates the duplicated task with no parent.

I know it shouldn't behave like that, but I'm not quite sure where to look for the answer.. I googled, wondered around the "process" options, but couldn't find the reason.

I wound be grateful for any hint...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it’s optional for user **whether include existing links** (including parent link) when copying a work item.

[image]

More details, you can refer [Copy or clone work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items).

Additional, for the copied work item, there will add a message in **Discussion** to show which work item it’s copied from, and also add the **related link** for the work item copied from.

Comment: How silly of me to overlook that immediate spot, scanning Google all over... but is there a way to make it checked by default?

Comment: No, it can not be changed. But there is an similar user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2453105-update-the-default-copy-workitem-function-to-allow, you can vote and follow up.

Comment: That user voice link is no longer valid. I got here because of the exact same question, how to make that "include existing links" checked by default.